# Using driver.quit() in parallel run

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running test in parallel using `parallel="classes"`. Till now i was closing browser using `driver.close()` in `@AfterClass`. Once test is run, window would close.

```html
public class DriverFactory {
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return setupChromeDriver();
    } 
 }
 
 public class Base {
 private final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
 @BeforeClass
 public void initialise() {
 driver.set(DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver()); 
 }
 
 public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
 }
    
 @AfterClass
 public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.get().close();
    driver.get().remove();
 }
 }
```

Recently i realised `close()` does not end driver session which caused many `chromedriver` and `geckodriver`instances to stay in memory after test suite is run. I had to kill manually using killall chromedriver.

**Solution** :
I tried with `driver.quit()` in `@AfterClass`, which worked fine and killed session nicely but it worked for test which are not running in parallel.

**Challenge**:
If i use `quit()` for parallel run, it closes all running windows. If i use it in `@AfterSuite`, it will work but it would not be ideal to leave all browser windows open until complete test suite is run . I have around 200 tests.

If i use `close()` in `@AfterClass` and use `quit()` in `@AfterSuite`, it gives no such session exception because driver is closed which is correct.

Chrome version : 83.0.4103.61
Chromedriver version : 83.0.4103.39
Selenium version : 3.141.59

Any help is appreciated here, thanks .

Comment: In above example in AfterClass driver.close(); is it typo ? You need to use driver.get().quit() as you are using ThreadLocal

Comment: Yes, it was typo. Corrected, thanks !!